# Using Windows Server 2012 How to Move Uploads Folder to another hard drive

Tags: uploads, wp-config, windows

Using Wordpress as an intranet. The Wordpress installation is on C however this drive is limited and wanting to use another hard drive on the server (Hard Drive E) for my uploads folder.

Am I able to change the UPLOADS dir via the config or will ABSPATH be an issue and need another work around?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the location of the uploads directory (and leave the rest of WordPress on C:), you should be able to define the `UPLOADS` constant:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', wp_normalize_path( 'e:\path\to\uploads' ) );
```

I'd recommend you do this on a test machine first, if at all possible. I'd also recommend you [do this in a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) somewhere — possibly a [Must-Use plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

**Caveat**: If you've already got files uploaded, you will probably need to move them manually to the new location. (I'm not sure if, but I suspect that, WordPress will find them there, as long as you maintain the same file names.)

## Reference

- [`wp_upload_dir()` » Folder Name](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/#folder-name)
- [`wp_normalize_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_normalize_path/) (to convert Windows paths for use by PHP)
- [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
- [Must-Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the help Pat however unfortunately this solution didn't work. We were unable to get the wp-config to read the directory and write to the directory. Not sure if the IIS permissions is our culprit or what. When placing it above the wp-settings we would get a 500 error. When placing it below we would get an error of unable to create directory.